# Graphical user interface on custom Linux OS with C#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I am creating a **Media center**. I have **customized a Linux operating system**, so as it boots up, it shows the splash screen and then runs a mono application (currently console app). The application itself would be the media center. Now **I need graphical user interface**, but I don't know how to start with that in **C# and mono**. Windows Forms application isn't getting it done for me, becouse I miss the animations and simplicity from WPF, wich can't run on Linux. What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/

Comment: As the other comment indicates, Mono project has its documentation listing all options. Don't bother SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for just something in C# to run on it, I would suggest Gtk#. 
If you're looking to make your own for your system, I would suggest looking at how the more mainstream C# GUI's are setup, and try to manipulate them for your own use.
For further information: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/